MLKIT MLKVisionImage import not found in KMP shared iosMain
MLKVisionImage import not found in KMP ios
Added below code
`cocoapods {
// Required properties
// Specify the required Pod version here. Otherwise, the Gradle project version is used.
version = "1.0"
summary = "Some description for a Kotlin/Native module"
homepage = "Link to a Kotlin/Native module homepage"
// Optional properties
// Configure the Pod name here instead of changing the Gradle project name
name = "MyCocoaPod"
ios.deploymentTarget = "12.0"

framework {
    // Required properties
    // Framework name configuration. Use this property instead of deprecated 'frameworkName'
    baseName = "MyFramework"

    // Optional properties
    // Specify the framework linking type. It's dynamic by default.
    isStatic = false
    // Dependency export

// export(project(":anotherKMMModule"))
@OptIn(ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
transitiveExport = false // This is default.
}
// Maps custom Xcode configuration to NativeBuildType
xcodeConfigurationToNativeBuildType["CUSTOM_DEBUG"] = NativeBuildType.DEBUG
xcodeConfigurationToNativeBuildType["CUSTOM_RELEASE"] = NativeBuildType.RELEASE

pod("GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning") {
    moduleName = "MLKitBarcodeScanning"
    version = "6.0.0"
}
pod("GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition") {
    moduleName = "MLKitTextRecognition"
    version = "6.0.0"
}

}`
this generates and links the MLKitBarcodeScanning and MLKitTextRecognition. I'm able to access these imports
import cocoapods.GoogleMLKit.MLKTextRecognizer
import cocoapods.GoogleMLKit.MLKBarcode
and other related.
But i'm not able to access the MLKVisionImage which also part of MLKTextRecognizer as per the official doc https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/v2/ios
To Reproduce
Example Steps to reproduce the behavior in sample app:

Add the above cocoa pods to KMP project
Sync the project
try to import the MLKVisionImage
should show error import not found

Expected behavior
import cocoapods.GoogleMLKit.MLKVisionImage should be available when MLKTextRecognizer pod is added.
SDK Info:
SDK GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition 6.0.0

Finally found need to add
pod("GoogleMLKit/Vision") { moduleName = "MLKitVision" version = "6.0.0" }

